# Where is my pc's mouse and keyboard?

Tags: linux

Maybe this is a general question:

How can I know which device files under the "/dev" directory are corresponded to my pc's mouse and keyboard?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on a lot of things (architecture, distribution, age of kernel, phase of the moon), but the most likely answer is `/dev/input/mouse*` is each mouse on the sysem, `/dev/input/mice` is the aggregation of all mice, and `/dev/input/uinput` is the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The answer these days is "Ask HAL or DeviceKit". Their job is to answer the question "Where can I find a mouse?"

Comment: Or more to the point, "How many mice do I have and which one am I using?". I blame laptops.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how new this is to [udev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) or [devfs](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/rgooch/linux/docs/devfs.html) (if using older kernel), or if it requires certain kernel compilation options, but with the Ubuntu Jaunty stock kernel you can do the following for the keyboard:

```
[kbrandt@opadmin: ~] ls -l /dev/input/by-id                                                                                        
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2009-06-22 10:35 usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2009-06-22 10:35 usb-Microsoft_Microsoft_Wireless_Optical_Desktop__1.00-event-kbd -> ../event3
```

Then notice where the symbolic link is point to on the left.  For verification, you can do something like:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/event5
```

Then type stuff in another window while that is running and you should see all sorts of characters filling the terminal.

You can do the same with the mouse# until you see more junk when moving the mouse, like:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/mouse1
```

There are probably  better ways, but they are probably not as fun:-)

Comment: On a pedantic note, the contents of /dev these days are managed by udev and not devfs. At least from 2.6.15 onward.